# I am unable to transfer data between two classes using interface in Android Studio with Java

Tags: java, android, android-studio, interface, data-transfer

I have an application where I set up the user interface completely programmatically, meaning I didn't draw the objects in XML. It works perfectly fine, but since I drew the objects in the content with different classes, I need to establish communication between the two classes. For example, if I press a button in Class1, I want to write the text on the button in Class2 and trigger the button in Class2 based on that. I think using an interface is the most logical solution for this, but I'm unable to transfer the data from Class1 to Class2 using the interface. I'm getting an error saying 'cannot be cast to...'

My GameInterface:

```
public interface GameInterface {

void seciliHucreyiDoldur(String seciliHucreyiDoldur);
}
```

Class1:

```
private class Cell implements GameInterface {
    int value;
    boolean fixed;
    Button btn;
    String hucreyiDolduracakVeri;
    Context THIS;

    public Cell(int initValue, Context THIS) {
        this.THIS = THIS;
        value = initValue;
        if (value != 0) {
            fixed = true;
        } else {
            fixed = false;
        }

        btn = new Button(THIS);
        btn.setTextSize(16);

        if (fixed) {
            btn.setText(String.valueOf(value));
        }

        txtSayac.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);


        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (fixed) {
                    Toast.makeText(THIS, "Bu hücreyi değiştiremezsiniz!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
                /*value++;
                if (value > 9) {
                    value = 1;
                }*/
                btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.hucre_arkaplani_kirmizimsi);
                btn.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                btn.setText(hucreyiDolduracakVeri);

                btn.setTextColor(Color.RED);

                if (correct()) {
                    textView.setText("");
                } else {
                    textView.setText("Tekrar eden rakamlar var, kontrol etmelisin!");
                }
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void seciliHucreyiDoldur(String seciliHucreyiDoldur) {
        this.hucreyiDolduracakVeri = seciliHucreyiDoldur;
        Toast.makeText(THIS, hucreyiDolduracakVeri, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if (fixed) {
            //Toast.makeText(THIS, "Bu hücreyi değiştiremezsiniz!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
                /*value++;
                if (value > 9) {
                    value = 1;
                }*/
        btn.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        btn.setText(seciliHucreyiDoldur);

        btn.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.hucre_arkaplani_mavi_acik);

        if (correct()) {
            textView.setText("");
        } else {
            textView.setText("Tekrar eden rakamlar var, kontrol etmelisin!");
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void hucreSeciliMi(boolean hucreSecilimi) {

    }
}
```

Class2:

```
public class AltBolumNumericTablo implements GameInterface{

    Button btnClick;
    boolean onClicked;
    int value;
    Activity activity;
    GameInterface gameInterface;

    public AltBolumNumericTablo(int value, Context THIS, Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.value = value;
        btnClick = new Button(THIS);
        btnClick.setTextSize(24f);

        gameInterface = (GameInterface) activity;

        switch (value) {
            case 0:
                btnClick.setText("1");
                break;
            case 1:
                btnClick.setText("2");

                break;
            case 2:
                btnClick.setText("3");

                break;
            case 3:
                btnClick.setText("4");

                break;
            case 4:
                btnClick.setText("5");

                break;
            case 5:
                btnClick.setText("6");

                break;
            case 6:
                btnClick.setText("7");

                break;
            case 7:
                btnClick.setText("8");

                break;
            case 8:
                btnClick.setText("9");

                break;
            case 9:
                btnClick.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sil_icon);
                break;
        }

        btnClick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                clickIslemleri(value);
            }
        });

    }

    public void clickIslemleri(int value) {

        switch (value) {
            case 0:
            case 1:
            case 2:
            case 3:
            case 4:
            case 5:
            case 6:
            case 7:
            case 8:
        gameInterface.seciliHucreyiDoldur(String.valueOf(value+1));
                break;
            case 9:
                gameInterface.seciliHucreyiDoldur("");
                break;
        }
    }

    public void kayitliOyunuGuncelle() {
        misafirOyunKaydiDB = new MisafirOyunKaydiDB(MainActivity.this);
        new MisafirGirisliOyunKaydiDAO().misafirgirisiKaydiGuncelle(misafirOyunKaydiDB,
                1, input + " s", 0, "00:45", kayitZamanini());
        misafirKaydiListesi = new MisafirGirisliOyunKaydiDAO().tumOyunKayitlari(misafirOyunKaydiDB);
        for (int i = 0; i < misafirKaydiListesi.size(); i++) {
            Log.e("saved game", misafirKaydiListesi.get(i).getTimestamp());
        }
    }

    public void gecmisOyunlarGuest() {
        misafirOyunKaydiDB = new MisafirOyunKaydiDB(MainActivity.this);
        misafirKaydiListesi = new MisafirGirisliOyunKaydiDAO().tumOyunKayitlari(misafirOyunKaydiDB);
        for (int i = 0; i < misafirKaydiListesi.size(); i++) {
            Log.e("saved game", misafirKaydiListesi.get(i).getId() + "");

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void seciliHucreyiDoldur(String seciliHucreyiDoldur) {

    }

    @Override
    public void hucreSeciliMi(Boolean hucreSecilimi) {

    }
}
```

Error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.devapost.mysudoku, PID: 4945
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.devapost.mysudoku.MainActivity cannot be cast to com.devapost.mysudoku.utils.GameInterface
    at com.devapost.mysudoku.MainActivity$AltBolumNumericTablo.<init>(MainActivity.java:514)
    at com.devapost.mysudoku.MainActivity.altNumericDoldur(MainActivity.java:297)
```

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GameInterface{
Cell[][] table;
AltBolumNumericTablo[][] tableAltNumeric;
MisafirGirisEkrani[] tableMisafir;
UyeMenuEkrani[] tableUyeMenusu;
String input;
TableLayout tableLayout;
TextView textView, txtSayac;
Button buttonGenerate;
LinearLayout linearLayout;
Button btnGoogleLoginMainScreen, btnMisafirMainScreen;
int hangiEkranda = 0;
MisafirOyunKaydiDB misafirOyunKaydiDB;
ArrayList<MisafirGirisliOyunKaydiModel> misafirKaydiListesi;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    girisSecenekleriEkrani();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    
    switch (hangiEkranda) {
        case 0:
        case 2://üye menusundeyse
            super.onBackPressed();
            linearLayout.removeAllViews();
            onBackPressed();
            break;
        case 1://misafir menusundeyse
            girisSecenekleriEkrani();
            break;
        case 3://misafir oyun ekranındaysa
            misafirOyunKaydiDB = new MisafirOyunKaydiDB(MainActivity.this);
            new MisafirGirisliOyunKaydiDAO().saveGame(misafirOyunKaydiDB, input, input, 5, txtSayac.getText().toString(), 1, kayitZamanini());
            misafirEkraniniDoldur();
            break;
        case 4://misafir ayarlardaysa
        case 5://misafirden nasıl oynanıra gittiyse
            misafirEkraniniDoldur();
            break;
        case 6://serüvene gittiyse
        case 7://rastgele oyun kurma ekranına gittiyse
        case 8://skorboard ekranına gittiyse
        case 9://üye ekranından ayarlara gittiyse
        case 10://üye ekranından nasıl oynanır ekranına gittiyse
            uyelerinMenusu();
            break;
    }


}

public String kayitZamanini() {
    Calendar anlikSaatDakika = Calendar.getInstance();
    int yil = anlikSaatDakika.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int ay = anlikSaatDakika.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    int gun = anlikSaatDakika.get(Calendar.SECOND);
    int saat = anlikSaatDakika.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int dakika = anlikSaatDakika.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    int saniye = anlikSaatDakika.get(Calendar.SECOND);
    return gun + "." + ay + "." + yil + " - " + saat + ":" + dakika + ":" + saniye;
}

public void girisSecenekleriEkrani() {//giriş seçenekleri ekranı
    hangiEkranda = 0;
    linearLayout = new LinearLayout(MainActivity.this);

    btnGoogleLoginMainScreen = new Button(MainActivity.this);
    btnMisafirMainScreen = new Button(MainActivity.this);

    btnGoogleLoginMainScreen.setText("Google İle Giriş Yap");
    btnMisafirMainScreen.setText("Misafir Girişi");
    btnGoogleLoginMainScreen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            uyelerinMenusu();
        }
    });

    btnMisafirMainScreen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            linearLayout.removeAllViews();
            misafirEkraniniDoldur();
        }
    });
    linearLayout.addView(btnGoogleLoginMainScreen);
    linearLayout.addView(btnMisafirMainScreen);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
    );
    linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    linearLayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    linearLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    setContentView(linearLayout);
}

public void yeniOyunMisafirIcin() {
    hangiEkranda = 3;
    linearLayout.removeAllViews();
    int N = 9, K = 25;
    Sudoku sudoku = new Sudoku(N, K);
    sudoku.fillValues();

    txtSayac = new TextView(MainActivity.this);

    input = sudoku.printSudoku();
    String[] split = input.split(" ");
    table = new Cell[9][9];
    tableLayout = new TableLayout(MainActivity.this);
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(MainActivity.this);

        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
            String s = split[i * 9 + j];
            char c = s.charAt(0);
            table[i][j] = new Cell(c == '?' ? 0 : c - '0', MainActivity.this);

            paintCellBackground(i, j, table[i][j].btn);
            tableRow.addView(table[i][j].btn);
        }
        tableLayout.addView(tableRow);
    }
    tableLayout.setShrinkAllColumns(true);
    tableLayout.setStretchAllColumns(true);
    textView = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
    buttonGenerate = new Button(MainActivity.this);
    linearLayout = new LinearLayout(MainActivity.this);

    linearLayout.addView(txtSayac);

    LinearLayout linearLayoutEkMetin = new LinearLayout(MainActivity.this);
    linearLayoutEkMetin.setLayoutParams(
            new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    linearLayoutEkMetin.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    linearLayoutEkMetin.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    buttonGenerate.setText("Generate");
    buttonGenerate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    buttonGenerate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            misafirEkraniniDoldur();
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    linearLayoutEkMetin.addView(buttonGenerate);
    linearLayout.addView(tableLayout);
    linearLayout.addView(textView);
    linearLayout.addView(linearLayoutEkMetin);
    linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    altNumericDoldur();
    setContentView(linearLayout);


}

public void paintCellBackground(int i, int j, Button button) {

    switch (i) {
        case 0:
        case 1:
        case 2:
        case 6:
        case 7:
        case 8:
            switch (j) {
                case 0:
                case 1:
                case 2:
                case 6:
                case 7:
                case 8:
                    button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.hucre_arkaplani_gri);
                    break;
                case 3:
                case 4:
                case 5:
                    button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.hucre_arkaplani_beyaz);
                    break;
            }
            break;
        case 3:
        case 4:
        case 5:
            switch (j) {
                case 0:
                case 1:
                case 2:
                case 6:
                case 7:
                case 8:
                    button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.hucre_arkaplani_beyaz);
                    break;
                case 3:
                case 4:
                case 5:
                    button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.hucre_arkaplani_gri);
                    break;
            }
            break;
    }

}

public void misafirEkraniniDoldur() {//misafir ekranını doldurur
    hangiEkranda = 1;
    tableMisafir = new MisafirGirisEkrani[5];
    tableLayout = new TableLayout(MainActivity.this);

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(MainActivity.this);
        tableMisafir[i] = new MisafirGirisEkrani(i, MainActivity.this);

        tableRow.addView(tableMisafir[i].btnClick);
        tableLayout.addView(tableRow);
    }
    tableLayout.setShrinkAllColumns(true);
    tableLayout.setStretchAllColumns(true);
    linearLayout = new LinearLayout(MainActivity.this);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    );
    layoutParams.setMarginStart(16);
    layoutParams.setMarginEnd(16);

    tableLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

    linearLayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

    linearLayout.addView(tableLayout);
    linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    setContentView(linearLayout);
}

public void altNumericDoldur() {//alt numerik tabloyu doldurur
    tableAltNumeric = new AltBolumNumericTablo[2][5];
    tableLayout = new TableLayout(MainActivity.this);

    int butonID = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(MainActivity.this);
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {

            tableAltNumeric[i][j] = new AltBolumNumericTablo(butonID, MainActivity.this,MainActivity.this);

            tableRow.addView(tableAltNumeric[i][j].btnClick);
            butonID++;
        }

        tableLayout.addView(tableRow);
    }
    tableLayout.setShrinkAllColumns(true);
    tableLayout.setStretchAllColumns(true);
    //linearLayout = new LinearLayout(MainActivity.this);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    );
    layoutParams.setMarginStart(16);
    layoutParams.setMarginEnd(16);

    tableLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

    linearLayout.addView(tableLayout);
    linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    setContentView(linearLayout);
}

private void uyelerinMenusu() {//google ile giriş yapanlar için serüven ekranı
    hangiEkranda = 2;
    tableUyeMenusu = new UyeMenuEkrani[5];
    tableLayout = new TableLayout(MainActivity.this);

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(MainActivity.this);
        tableUyeMenusu[i] = new UyeMenuEkrani(i, MainActivity.this);

        tableRow.addView(tableUyeMenusu[i].btnClick);
        tableLayout.addView(tableRow);
    }
    tableLayout.setShrinkAllColumns(true);
    tableLayout.setStretchAllColumns(true);
    linearLayout = new LinearLayout(MainActivity.this);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    );
    layoutParams.setMarginStart(16);
    layoutParams.setMarginEnd(16);

    tableLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

    linearLayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

    linearLayout.addView(tableLayout);
    linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    setContentView(linearLayout);

}

@Override
public void seciliHucreyiDoldur(String seciliHucreyiDoldur) {

}

@Override
public void hucreSeciliMi(boolean hucreSecilimi) {

}

public class UyeMenuEkrani {

    Button btnClick;
    boolean onClicked;
    int value;

    public UyeMenuEkrani(int value, Context THIS) {
        this.value = value;
        btnClick = new Button(THIS);
        switch (value) {
            case 0:
                btnClick.setText("Serüven");
                break;
            case 1:
                btnClick.setText("Rastgele Oyna");
                break;
            case 2:
                btnClick.setText("Skor Tablosu");
                break;
            case 3:
                btnClick.setText("Ayarlar");
                break;
            case 4:
                btnClick.setText("Nasıl Oynanır");
                break;
        }

        btnClick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                clickIslemleri(value);
            }
        });

    }

    public void clickIslemleri(int value) {
        switch (value) {
            case 0://seruven
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "serüvene gider", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case 1://rastgele
                yeniOyunMisafirIcin();//rastgele ekranı misafir giriş ekranına gider, çok benzer zaten
                break;
            case 2://skorboard
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "skorboard", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case 3://ayarlar
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "ayarlar", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case 4://nasıl oynanır
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "nasıl oynanır", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case 5:

                break;
        }

    }
}

public class MisafirGirisEkrani {

    Button btnClick;
    boolean onClicked;
    int value;

    public MisafirGirisEkrani(int value, Context THIS) {
        this.value = value;
        btnClick = new Button(THIS);


        switch (value) {
            case 0:
                btnClick.setText("Yeni Oyun");
                break;
            case 1:
                btnClick.setText("Devam Et");

                break;
            case 2:
                btnClick.setText("Ayarlar");

                break;
            case 3:
                btnClick.setText("Giriş Yap");

                break;
            case 4:
                btnClick.setText("Nasıl Oynanır");

                break;
        }

        btnClick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                clickIslemleri(value);
            }
        });

    }

    public void clickIslemleri(int value) {
        switch (value) {
            case 0:
                yeniOyunMisafirIcin();
                break;
            case 1://eski oyunları listele ve onlardan seçip devam et
                gecmisOyunlarGuest();

                break;
            case 2:
                kayitliOyunuGuncelle();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "ayarlar", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case 3:
                girisSecenekleriEkrani();
                break;
            case 4:
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "nasıl oynanır", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
        }

    }

    public void kayitliOyunuGuncelle() {
        misafirOyunKaydiDB = new MisafirOyunKaydiDB(MainActivity.this);
        new MisafirGirisliOyunKaydiDAO().misafirgirisiKaydiGuncelle(misafirOyunKaydiDB,
                1, input + " s", 0, "00:45", kayitZamanini());
        misafirKaydiListesi = new MisafirGirisliOyunKaydiDAO().tumOyunKayitlari(misafirOyunKaydiDB);
        for (int i = 0; i < misafirKaydiListesi.size(); i++) {
            Log.e("saved game", misafirKaydiListesi.get(i).getTimestamp());
        }
    }

    public void gecmisOyunlarGuest() {
        misafirOyunKaydiDB = new MisafirOyunKaydiDB(MainActivity.this);
        misafirKaydiListesi = new MisafirGirisliOyunKaydiDAO().tumOyunKayitlari(misafirOyunKaydiDB);
        for (int i = 0; i < misafirKaydiListesi.size(); i++) {
            Log.e("saved game", misafirKaydiListesi.get(i).getId() + "");

        }
    }
}

boolean complated() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
            if (table[i][j].value == 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}

boolean correct(int i1, int j1, int i2, int j2) {
    boolean[] seen = new boolean[10];
    for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
        seen[i] = false;
    }
    for (int i = i1; i < i2; i++) {
        for (int j = j1; j < j2; j++) {
            int value = table[i][j].value;
            if (value != 0) {
                if (seen[value]) {
                    return false;
                }
                seen[value] = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}

boolean correct() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        if (!correct(i, 0, i + 1, 9)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
        if (!correct(0, j, 9, j + 1)) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            if (!correct(3 * i, 3 * j, 3 * i + 3, 3 * j + 3)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: Can you add code of ```MainActivity```

Comment: @jayeshgurudayalani I added my MainActivity.java code

Answer (score 0):

Got the issue .
Issue is at below mentioned line in `AltBolumNumericTablo` class

```
gameInterface = (GameInterface) activity;
```

you just need to change as mentioned below

From

```
public AltBolumNumericTablo(int value, Context THIS, Activity activity)
```

To

```
public AltBolumNumericTablo(int value, Context THIS, GameInterface gameInterfaceParam){
  gameInterface = gameInterfaceParam
   .. existing code
}
```

Comment: I did as you said but I can only access it from MainActivity.java. The data I want to send is not sent into the Cell class. I want to use the data I sent from the AltBolumNumericTable class in the Cell class.

Comment: Not getting clear idea what issue you are facing .. can you add error or SS or video of issue

Comment: Video: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qheJjaYAoBDeGG_B0FoQrBO_wcSpD_qV

SS Image: https://pasteboard.co/l9TThqgJ6Bfd.png
What I want to do is print 3 in the selected box when I press 3 for example.
The following section: AltBolumNumericTablo class
Above section: Cell class